# Homology with coefficinets

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology

I am a bit confused working with the definition of Homology with coefficients from Brown's Book on Cohomology of groups. To define $H_*(G,M)$ we take a projective resolution $F$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ and define $H_*(G,M)= H_*(F\otimes_G M)$ where this tensor product is made in a way that transform a left module into a right module so that $F\otimes_G M = (F\otimes M)_G$. Latter when proving Shapiro's Lemma he states that $H_*(G,M)\cong H_*(F\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}M)$ where this tensor product is the usual where $F$ has its normal $G$-action. I dont quite see why this isomorphism is true, so any help would be aprecciated. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two $G$-modules $M,N$, $M\otimes_G N \cong M\otimes_{\mathbb Z[G]}N$.

Indeed, $M\otimes_{\mathbb Z[G]} N$ is obtained from $M\otimes N$ by modding out $mg\otimes n - m\otimes gn$, and those are the same relations as modding out $g\cdot (m\otimes n) - m\otimes n$ where $g\cdot (m\otimes n) = mg^{-1}\otimes gn$ is the diagonal action.

(to see that they're the same relations, simply put $m' := mg$ in the second one, and see that it gives you the first one)

Comment: Thanks for the ansewr but in exercise $1.b)$ of section 5.5 of Brown's Book on group cohomology, he says to give an example where $M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}N$ is not isomorphic to $M \otimes_G N$ so after seeing this i am a bit confused.

Comment: Look at the parenthesis of that exercise. The point is that there are a bunch of notions of "tensor product over $G$" and they don't give the same result in general. The point is that you can either say $(gm)\otimes n = m\otimes (gn)$, or you can say $(mg)\otimes n = m\otimes (gn)$, where $M$ will then be a *right* $G$-module. Normally you "shouldn't be able to compare them, but in fact you can, because any left $G$-module can be turned into a right $G$-module via $mg := g^{-1}m$. So in fact, if you have two left $G$-modules, there are two things you can define :

Comment: I mean the parenthesis referts to the usual tensor product in commutative rings right ?

Comment: one with $(gm)\otimes n = m\otimes (gn)$ and one with $(g^{-1}m)\otimes n = m\otimes (gn)$. It's reasonable to expect that they won't be isomorphic. The first one amounts to quotienting $M\otimes N$ by the antidiagonal action, and the second one by the diagonal action

Comment: So apparently, what Brown calls "$M\otimes_G N$" is $(M\otimes N)_G$ with the diagonal action. That's a bit weird, but ok. That's not a problem though, because for $F$ a free module, both notions of $F\otimes_G M$ coincide ! That's because $F$ is free as a right or as a left-module. Is it clearer now ? (I personnally learned $M\otimes_G N$ defined as tensor product over $\mathbb Z[G]$ with $M$ seen as a right $G$-module, hence my initial answer - you can see that from my answer actually)